# How to handle cyclic foreign key insertion?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table **'release_group'** and another table **'release'**, like so:

```
release_group 
------------------------
release_group_id (PRIMARY KEY)
name
main_release_id (FOREIGN KEY)

release
------------------------
release_id (PRIMARY KEY)
release_group_id (FOREIGN KEY)
name
```

If i create a release row, the **release_group_id** is not available, simply because it hasn't been created yet. But i can't create a release_group row without the **main_release_id**. So it's kind of a no way situation.

EDIT:
The main_release_id in release_group is to say that the release is the main from the group, the one i will use a reference.

What is the professional way of handling this case?

1.
Remove the foreign key index  **main_release_id** in table **release_group** and give an attribute ALLOW NULL. Create the release_group row so i can applied it's id in the release row.

2.
Keep the 'main_release_id' foreign key index in table 'release_group' and assign it a temporary integer value of 0. Create the release row and update the foreign key in the release_group accordingly? Keep in mind that if this is the way to go, i could end up inadvertently having foreign keys with value 0, which i don't know if this ethic in a database?

What is the professional way of handling this case?

Thanks

Comment: i'd say drop one of those foreign keys, and make it a local key index for querying and joining purpose.

Comment: by local, you mean a simple key that allows null values ?

Comment: What is the relationship you're trying to maintain, one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many.  It's hard to understand what the underlying goal you're trying to accomplish with the current schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seeing how a release cannot belong to more than one group, you could remove the complication by:

1. Dropping the `main_release_id` field altogether
2. Add a `release_main` field to the `release` table; it would be `NULL` (not main) or `1` (main).
3. Add a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(release_group_id, release_main)` to make sure there can only be one main release.

**Update**

If a release can belong to multiple groups, you would need to create a many-to-many table and move the foreign key in both tables into it:

```
(release_group_id [FK], release_id [FK], is_main)
```

The primary key would span the first two fields. Ensuring that there can only be one main release requires a spanning unique key over the first and last field.

**Old answer**

Assuming `main_release_id` is a nullable field, what I would suggest is the following:

1. Insert the `release_group` with `main_release_id` being `null`; get last inserted id.
2. Insert the `release` entry, passing the id of the previous step; get last inserted id.
3. Update the `release_group` table entry, setting the value of `main_release_id` to the value you got from the previous step.
4. Commit transaction

Alternatively, you could use sequences so that you know the id before inserting the entries. See an example of this in the manual under [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

Comment: this mean that the foreign key release_id in release_group must ALLOW NULL, therefore it should be a simple key and NOT a primary key, right?

Comment: ok, so use a key and not a primary key (primary key can't be null)

Comment: main_release_id cannot be a primary key in table release_group if it should be null

Comment: i though you could have to primary keys in mysql, sorry my mistake

Comment: @Marco Expanded the answer to highlight the "flag" way in more detail.

Comment: so it is , after all, the flag solution that everyone is suggesting, the ideal solution. I wish i could accept more then 1 answer. Thanks

Comment: @Marco Yeah, with the added constraints that are required to make sure only one can be the main release :)

Comment: if i'm not mistaking, the constraint should be on (release_group_id, release_main)

Comment: actually, i've just tested this solution and it will not work simply because a release could be in more than 1 release_group. And i absolutely need to know the main release of the group. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @Marco Your current table design doesn't actually allow a release to be in more than one group, so I've added a solution to that as well.

Comment: Back to my original solution :)  BTW, rethinking the unique constraints, i don't believe it will work.  A unique constraint like the one describe will not allow there to be more than one release related to the release_group with a null main_release flag.  This should be handled in the code.

Comment: @Hess Sigh, tell me about it :)

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you are trying to create a many to many relationship. To do this properly, remove the foreign keys from both the release_group and release tables.  Add a new table (release_to_release_group) that contains the release_id foreign key and the release foreign key.

Edit: There is no need for cyclic foreign keys here.  Remove the main_release_id foreign_key from release_group and add a is_main_release flag to the release table.

Comment: the reason is that the release group can have multiple releases and one of those releases is the main release, the one i will use as a reference.

Comment: add a flag for the primary release to the many to many table.

Comment: Will a release ever be in more than one release group?

Comment: no. never. i think the terminology i've use could be confusing. i will change it

Comment: Remove the main_release_id foreign_key from release_group.  Add a is_main_release flag to the release table.

Comment: you're the second user whose suggesting the flag solution. Maybe that's the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

It's not usual practice to have the tables reference each other like that. Usually you would have the Parent table (release_group) as a foreign key reference in the child table (release), but not have the release_id as a foreign key in the release_group table.

Maybe add a boolean flag to the release table to indicate it is the Main release and do away with the main_release_id in release_group.

Comment: the reason is that the release group can have multiple releases and one of those releases is the main release, the one i will use as a reference.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question; it should be a comment, which you will be able to post when you gain 5 more rep points :)

Comment: Maybe put a boolean flag on the release table to indicate if it's the main release or not and get rid of the release_id fk ?

Comment: @Jack will do. Just getting used to SO rules and regs {:O)

Comment: that is another solution that i haven't though off, to have a flag on the release_table. Im not sure if it's better solution than to have the id in the table release_group

Comment: If you have a flag in the release table, you will need to add logic to ensure that only one of the release records can be the main one. Depending on how you are updating the tables, that may not be ideal...

Comment: that is what i'm afraid off, that i will end up having more then one main release associated with a release group

Comment: I haven't got the rep to comment on solution from @Jack, but I don't think adding a unique constraint would work, since you could have two records with the main release flag set to 1 which had different release ids. They would be unique, but you would have two different releases marked as main.